# How to get content inside html tags including the tags using regex in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I have text below -

```
how  much  production  in  batu
```

Now this text appears as a series of `html` tags. Basically each word is wrapped in a `span` with a specific `style` or `class`. Here is how it looks like

```
'<span style="">how &nbsp;</span><span style="">much &nbsp;</span><span class="pink-highlight">production &nbsp;</span><span style="">in &nbsp;</span><span class="yellow-highlight">batu</span>'
```

Now I want two things from this `html` string: style or class and content inside the span (without `&nbsp;`)

So I would want an `array` of following information from the string

```
[["", "how"], ["", "much"], ["pink-highlight", "production"], ["", "in"], ["yellow-highlight", "batu"]]
```

Now this can be easily done using `regex`. But I am not well versed with `regex`. The pattern that I could think of

```
<span>(.*?)</span>
```

But it will only find out the content inside `span` and it won't even work in this case since each `span` has a `style` tag or a class.

So what `regex` would best apply in this case to get the desired result?

Comment: Just parse it as HTML and use DOM methods

Comment: "Now this can be easily done using regex" — Ahahahaha. No. https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/19068

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a reg exp can fail with matching HTML. It is pretty easy to just parse it as HTML and get the data.

```js
var html = '<span style="">how &nbsp;</span><span style="">much &nbsp;</span><span class="pink-highlight">production &nbsp;</span><span style="">in &nbsp;</span><span class="yellow-highlight">batu</span>'

var temp = document.createElement('div')
temp.innerHTML = html
var data = Array.from(temp.querySelectorAll('span'))
  .map(span =>
    ([
      span.getAttribute("style") || span.getAttribute("class") || '', span.textContent.trim()
    ])
  )
console.log(data)
```

Comment: great! This is what I needed. I didn't know there is difficulty in parsing html. This solution doesn't use regex and is simple too. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I will provide a simple regex. Actually I just added 2 more options.

```
(<span>(.*?)<\/span>)|(<span style=".*?">(.*?)<\/span>)|(<span class=".*?">(.*?)<\/span>)
```